# Hard Disk Full but Files size is about half the hard disk size

Tags: 14.04, disk-usage

My hard disk appears to be full.

I have 239,4 GiB in the hard disk according to Filelight

But according to Gparted I only have 24,53 GiB free out of 463,79

I tried some commands like:

```
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove
```

and also to use the application sweeper but I only gained some MiB

What could be happening?

The system is Ubuntu 14.04 fully updated.

The output of `df -h` - as requested:

```
Filesystem Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sdb1 457G 432G 1,4G 100% / 
none      4,0K 0    4,0K 0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
udev      978M 12K  978M 1% /dev 
tmpfs     198M 1,4M 197M 1% /run 
none      5,0M 0    5,0M 0% /run/lock 
none      988M 25M  964M 3% /run/shm
none      100M 60K  100M 1% /run/user
```

Comment: Perhaps you limited Filelight to only show a subdirectory?

Comment: I have got various users configured in the system, all of them administrators and I have found that filelight do not count all the files in the other users home directory. The total size of the file system when exploring the root directory is 239,5 GiB from one user but 416,6 GiB from the other user. I tried execute Filelight as root user but did not work... anyway, I found the files that were filling the file system... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have got various users configured in the system, all of them administrators, and I have found that Filelight does not count files in other users' home directories.

The total size of the file system when exploring the root directory is 239,5 GiB from one user but 416,6 GiB from the other user. I tried executing Filelight as root user but it didn't work... anyway, I found the files that were filling the file system.